# When is buffer-quit-function executed?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to hook into change-buffer, so tried to use `buffer-quit-function`.
I wrote the following code and evaluated (using `C-x C-e`):

```
(add-hook 'buffer-quit-function    (lambda () (message "Buffer quit!")))
```

After that, I tried to change buffer with using `C-x o` (other-window),  `C-x b` (switch-to-buffer.)
But I can not see string `Buffer quit!`.

Why is my `buffer-quit-function` not executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things wrong:

1. `buffer-quit-function` is not a hook.  It's a variable, so set it like

   ```
   (set (make-local-variable 'buffer-quit-function)
        (lambda () (message "Buffer quit!")))
   ```
2. It is not called when changing buffers; it's used when the user invokes `keyboard-escape-quit`, which is normally bound to `ESC ESC ESC`.

I don't think there's any mechanism provided to do what you're trying to do.